# unable to rename a key conditionally in json

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small JSON code that should take the key values and create a new JSON. I am able to do it using the below code. But here I want to rename the key based on a condition.

```js
var data = [{
  'name': 'a',
  'val': 5
}, {
  'name': 'b',
  'val': 6
}, {
  'name': 'c',
  'val': 25
}, ]


var hash = data.reduce(function(p, c) {
var n = c.name;

  p[n] = p[n] || {};
  if (n == 'a')
    n= 'r';
  p[n] = c.val;
  return p;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(hash).map(function(e) {
  let el = {};
  el[e] = hash[e];
  return el;
});

console.log(result);
```

Expected output is

```
[ {
  r: 5
}, {
  b: 6
}, {
  c: 25
}]
```

please let me know where am I going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single liner map() and a computed property

```js
const data=[{name:"a",val:5},{name:"b",val:6},{name:"c",val:25}];

const res = data.map(({name:n, val:v}) => ({[n === 'a' ? 'r' : n]: v}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove `p[n] = p[n] || {};`.

When `n` is `a`, it creates the unwanted `a: {}` that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I was writing some code and apparently I misunderstood the question. So my code does something else instead, not super relevant tho lol. FWIW

```
function translate(data, matrix) {
    return data.map(
        map=>Object.fromEntries(
            Object.keys(map).map(key => [matrix[key]||key, map[key]])
        )
    )
}

translate(data, {"name": "foo"})
// [ { foo: 'a', val: 5 }, { foo: 'b', val: 6 }, { foo: 'c', val: 25 } ]
```